# Testing for validity

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know the difference (if any) between the following:

```
if( someDOMElement.someProperty )
{
...

if( someDOMElement.someProperty != null )
{
...

if( someDOMElement.someProperty != undefined )
{
...
```

Is one safer than the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those will all do the same thing, and one isn't more error-prone than the others. Whereas if you were using `!==` rather than `!=`, the second two would only be true if the value really were `null` (the second one) or `undefined` (the third one), because the `!==` operator doesn't do coercion.

Javascript will coerce values during comparisons with `!=` or `==`, so for example:

```
alert(false == 0);   // alerts "true"
alert(false === 0);  // alerts "false"
```

The `===` and `!==` operators let you control that behavior. The rules for what coercions occur are [detailed in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (and a bit complicated), but just a simple "is this thing not `0`, `""`, `null`, or `undefined`?" can be written simply `if (thingy)` and it works well. `0`, `""`, `null`, and `undefined` are all "*falsey*".

Sean Kinsey [has a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896716/testing-for-validity/2896803#2896803) about some host objects, though I think most if not all DOM element properties will be fine. In particular, I've seen COM objects exhibit some interesting behavior, such as `if (comObject.property)` evaluating `true` when `if (comObject.property == null)` *also* evaluates `true`. (In my case, it was COM objects exposed as part of the server-side API of a product I was using; I use Javascript server-side as well as client-side.) Worth being aware that that can happen. When you're dealing with Javascript objects and (in my experience) DOM objects, you're fine.

Comment: So.. silly question. if( ! someThing ) Would work as expected.. right ? :-)

Comment: @Konrad: Not a silly question. Yes, it would. You see things like this all the time, for instance: `if (!optionalArg) { optionalArg = defaultValue; }` (although you also see the "functional" version a lot too: `optionalArg = optionalArg || defaultValue;`). You need to be careful when doing that with args where `false`, `0`, `""`, etc. are valid values, though. :-) Took me an hour to find a bug some months back where I'd happily done `a = a || 5;` and wasn't getting the result I expected (because I was passing `a = 0` into it, but of course, then overwriting that!).

Comment: Great. Thanks for the really useful answer and feedback. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that someDOMElement is not null, no particular differences:

http://www.steinbit.org/words/programming/comparison-in-javascript

There would be a difference if you use !==

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what `someDOMElement` is then these can have very different results, and none of them are 'safe' to use if Host Objects are involved (objects implemented as ActiveXObjects for instance).

You should really use a method such as one of these

```
// use this if you expect a callable property
function isHostMethod(object, property){
    var t = typeof object[property];
    return t == 'function' ||
    (!!(t == 'object' && object[property])) ||
    t == 'unknown';
}

// use this if you are only looking for a property
function isHostObject(object, property){
    return !!(typeof(object[property]) == 'object' && object[property]);
}

alert(isHostObject(someDOMElement, "someProperty"))
```

You can read more about proper feature detection at http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you call a value.

```
if(someDOMElement && someDOMElement.someProperty !=undefined){
    the property exists and has been set to a value other than undefined or null-
    it may be 0, false, NaN or the empty string, as well as any truthy value
}
```